# Invoke remote lambda function in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, terraform

How can I invoke an existing lambda function from one of my AWS accounts in my terraform code?

i have the lambda name, arn and ID alongside with account number that is hosting the lambda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [aws_lambda_invocation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_invocation):

> Use this data source to **invoke custom lambda functions** as data source. The lambda function is invoked with RequestResponse invocation type.